# How to use a Django model containing an image with an opencv function that modifies the image according to scroll bar value

Tags: jquery, json, django, opencv

I am building a site for my thesis that has images stored in the database and the user uses some scroll bars to change the brightness, contrast and blur of the current image (without refresing the page).

I've build the models and show the image in the template using it's ulr.

```
# in models.py:
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=700)
    full_image= models.FileField()
```

I have also written the js needed for the scroll bars and keep each value in a variable:

```
// eg: Focus Control
$( function() {
    $( "#focus-selector" ).slider({
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 255,
        step: 5,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#focus-amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    }) 
    $( "#focus-amount" ).val($( "#slider" ).slider.value );
});
```

I now need a way to get the variable "focus-amount" and the image from the model and pass it on my open cv function to change the blurriness of the image. I think I need to use JSON but I'm not exactly sure where and how.

Also, do I have to save the modified image in my model each time it changes? Or I should save the image to a different variable and display that one? And for these reads and saves do I just use imread and imwrite with the image's url?

I hope I explained everything correctly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all you need with js (HTML5 canvas). The example of [image mainupaltions](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) with js or you can use one of a lot of libraries [CaMan JS](http://camanjs.com/).
After manipulation you can pass image to server via JSON as BASE64 encoded string.